# How to make the content of a SmartGWT label not trim spaces?

Tags: java, gwt, user-interface, smartgwt, trim

Pretty self-explanatory. Whenever I set the contents of a label, any spaces at the beginning or end are removed. I've looked at the API and found little to help me. setExtraSpaces() will add spacing to the top and bottom, which I don't want. Something like setLeft doesn't seem to add any actual space -- perhaps some other layout is conflicting to cause that not to happen but even then it seems like a bit of a work around. So, basically, I just want to know if there's any way to make the content exactly what I put in?

Comment: I'm using &nbsp; for now, but I am still curious if there's some better way of handling this.

Comment: That's just how HTML works. Whitespace is removed. You need to use special tags that preserve whitespace, such as `<pre>` or use the `&nbsp;` HTML entity to insert non breaking space.

Comment: You should consider adding basic HTML and CSS into your repertoire. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219851/what-is-the-proper-way-to-align-two-buttons-in-the-same-row-with-htmlpanel-in-gw/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the JavaDoc:

```
setContents
```

public void setContents(String contents)

```
The contents of a canvas or label widget. **Any HTML string is acceptable**.
```

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I ended up doing, using html inside it.